# debugging an executable created by application

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm having a difficult time finding the right keywords to search on for this.  I'm simply trying to figure out a way to debug an executable file that was created by my application.  I just created an executable file from my application that contains some encrypted stuff which starts my application when double clicked, that my application uses for certain things.  Is it possible to run that executable program that starts the application, and debug the entry into visual studio?  I need to verify that the encrypted data is decrypted properly in the application, and the only way to verify this is with debug, or writing to an output file the decrypted information.  I'd rather just debug, so I don't have to remember to take out the code that produces the outfile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the "application" you've written a *compiler*? Because otherwise, I don't see how it would be generating an executable file.

Comment: You should be testing the encryption and decryption separately to the application. If they work outside the application, then chances are it'll work inside the application. If it doesn't, then its your "compiler" that's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I probably chose a bad choice of words.  I have created an application, and in that application the user can save a file that contains various information.  The file created has an extension of .abc.  The .abc extension has been added to the registry via the program installer, so the file the user saved ends up having an icon associated with it.  When the user double clicks this file going forward, I want it to open the application, disable some functionality, and go straight to where the file should take it in the application.  I would like to debug through visual studio if possible?

Comment: If you have the code of the application, please insert Debugger.Break to the proper places, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/10/03/debugger-break.aspx. Generally speaking, WinDbg is a better choice for debugging in this case, but Debugger.Break to give you most of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you application is installed with the .PDBs in the directory with it.

In visual studio, load the solution containing your application.

After you have started the app by double clicking on the associated icon select debug| attach to process ...

Select your process.

If you application is going right into action you may have to add a thread.sleep(10000) (or show a modal dialog) to give you time to attach  to the start while you debug - remove it when done.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I'll give this a try and see if it works.  I hope it does, since I haven't found any alternatives so far!

Comment: Well, I'm using Visual studio 2010 express, and it seems as though "attach to process" is not available in this version.  I'm beginning to think I might be out of luck.  Do you agree?

Comment: You might be. You can simulate what is happening by starting your app with a command line. If you right click on the project file in the solution explorer and select properties, you can select the debug tab and enter arguments and try it out like that by using the arguments from the file association.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Debug normally helps me out when I'm not sure how something is supposed to work.  I built a file with a bunch of info, but I'm not sure after double clicking the .exe, what even the entry point will be into the program, and what the parms will look like.  I'll keep pounding away with google and hopefully I will figure it out.  I'm going to go ahead and mark the answer as approved, because I'm sure that would probably have worked with Visual studio professional!